# Replace the current clipboard selection with a modified version of the original selection

Tags: bash, scripts, shortcut-keys, clipboard

I read the present topics on AskUbuntu, but none of them did fit exactly.

**Situation is:**
I want to replace the currently selected text (by calling a bash script via [EasyStroke](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki)) with a modified version of this text. The text is modified by RegEx'es or so... it's part of the script, so it doesn't really matter.

**Current state:**
I can read the selection from the ClipBoard with [xclip](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/f5eb9a91973b62a0f71b4c4c6fbb9e03), modify it and copy it back to the ClipBoard with the following command (part of the called bash script):

```
xclip -o | sed 's/ab/ef/g' | xclip -sel clip
```

The test string is

```
cdabcdabcdabcdab
```

And after applying the above command, the output (in the ClipBoard) is

```
cdefcdefcdefcdef
```

which is correct. But the result is still stored in the ClipBoard and **not** pasted back to the application. I have to paste it to the currently running application with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> manually.

**Question is:**
How can I automate the last step of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to immediately paste the result to the application in which the source text has been selected?

I tried `xclip` and `xsel`, but I was unable to make them work the way described above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `xdotool` has a `type` command to enter text in a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@meuh's](https://askubuntu.com/users/421483/meuh) comment above, I was able to complete this task:

1. Install these programs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y install xclip xdotool libnotify-bin
   ```
2. Create a `.bash` script for the transformation:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Script to replace selection with a 'sed' transformed output (callable with easystroke or similar)
   IN=`xclip -o`
   # Example: Replace all 'ab' by 'ef'
   RESULT=`echo "$IN" | sed -e 's/ab/ef/g`
   # Output result to clipboard
   xdotool type "$RESULT"
   # Transform result to HTML for output with notify-send
   RESULT_HTML=`echo "$RESULT" | sed 's/&/\&amp;/g; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g'`
   # Create a notification in the lower right corner with the transformation
   notify-send  "Changed clipboard text" "Input: $IN\nOutput: $RESULT_HTML"
   ```
3. Call this script from [easystroke](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Easystroke/) or a similar program that processes key- or mouse-strokes.